# htaccess rewrite en redirect not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, rewriting

I am new with .htaccess, and I tried a few things but it's not working..

I have now: http://localhost/sitecms/page.php?page=asd

And I want: http://localhost/sitecms/asd

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^sitecms/(.*)$ /page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Can someone help me and explain what I am doing wrong?

Edit:

This is my full current htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login?$ login.php
RewriteRule ^bewerken?$ admin/list.php


RewriteRule page/([^\n]+) page.php?page=$1 // this wil made localhost/page/asd
```

Comment: I have a suspicion this may be because the $1 variable you have at the end actually matches the first fragment of your pattern. In this case, that first fragment would be `sitecms`.

Maybe what you're looking for is something like:
`RewriteRule ^sitecms/(.*)$ sitecms/page.php?page=$2 [L]` ?

Comment: @Jean-RémyDuboc No, capturing subpatterns are created with parentheses, starting at 1.  There is no `$2` in OP's or your rule.  https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight! I'm no expert in this, just stabbing in the dark her :)

Comment: @Don'tPanic
This is not working for me.. Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually, please check your spelling and try again. If you believe this server is in error, please contact the webmaster. Error 404 localhost Apache / 2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL / 1.0.2e PHP / 7.0.6

Comment: @Danny I am not sure if you are still looking to redirect `sitecms/asd`? What directory is your `.htaccess` file in - is it in the top level `/`, or is it in `sitecms/`?

Comment: I found it, I needed only `RewriteBase /sitecms/` and `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ page.php?page=$1`

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing `sitecms/` in your target:

```
RewriteRule ^sitecms/(.*)$ /sitecms/page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

You might also want to add the `QSA` flag, to make sure any query string in the original is appended:

```
RewriteRule ^sitecms/(.*)$ /sitecms/page.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This is not working for me..

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually, please check your spelling and try again.

If you believe this server is in error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache / 2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL / 1.0.2e PHP / 7.0.6

Comment: Does `http://localhost/sitecms/page.php?page=asd` work?  If yes, are you still returning a `404` depending on what `asd` is?

Comment: When I try this code: 

`RewriteRule page/([^\n]+) page.php?page=$1`
`RewriteRule $1/([^\n]+) page/$`

I can go to http://localhost/sitecms/page/asd

But I need http://localhost/sitecms/asd

Comment: There is no way that a target `page.php?page=$1` will work, if `page.php` is in the directory `/sitecms/`, with the code you've shown us.  Are you using `RewriteBase`?  Some other code in your `.htaccess` you aren't showing us?  Anything related to redirects, or aliases for this dir, in the main Apache config or vhost config?

Comment: This is my full code:

`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteRule ^login?$ login.php`
`RewriteRule ^bewerken?$ admin/list.php`


`RewriteRule page/([^\n]+) page.php?page=$1`
`RewriteRule $1/([^\n]+) page/$1`

Comment: What happened to `sitecms`? Can you edit your question to include the code, it is hard to read here.  BTW AFAICT the last one will not do anything, you can't have `$1` in your pattern.